# ionicModal disapears after a few seconds

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use $ionicModal.
when I call `$scope.codeModal.show();`  modal pops up but immediately disapears. but when I click on the modal , it appears.
here is my Angular code:

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/resetCodeTemplate.html', {
        scope: $scope
      })
        .then(function (modal) {
          $scope.codeModal = modal;
        });

$scope.resetBaseCodeShow = function () {
        $scope.codeModal.show();
      };
```

any Idea why it happens?

Answer (score 1):

Use $timeout.

```
$scope.closeModal = function () {
  $scope.codeModal.hide();
};

$timeout($scope.closeModal, 5000);
```

Comment: I don't think that's the solution and it didn't work.